# Group of order 30 sylow-subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory, sylow-theory

Let G be a group of order 30, and suppose that both its Sylow 3-subgroup is unique and its Sylow 5-subgroup is unique. What group(s) can (or must) G “be”? What if only one of those conditions holds in G?

So I have been able to figure out the conditions when both are unique, but what if only one is unique, currently at a standstill.

Comment: The title you picked mentions a Sylow subgroup of order 30, and such a thing does not exist.